# Creating a recursive function which outputs a different datatype and can use it on each call?

Tags: c#, templates, recursion

I have a template class, as below:

```
public class Collections<T, U>
    {
        public Dictionary<T,U> collection;
        public Collections()
        {
            collection = new Dictionary<T,U>();
        }
    }
```

My data structure contains a number of collections, which are then collections of them selves such as:

```
ShareCollection = Collections<int, SiteCollection>
SiteCollection = Collections<int, WebCollection>
WebCollection = Collections<int, ListCollection>
ListCollection = Collections<int, ItemCollection>
ItemCollection = Collection<int, string>
```

In my actual code, I then call a function which takes the top level collection as an input argument, does something with this collections first value, then calls a second function with the argument as the second collection:

```
void ShareCollectionIterator(ShareCollection s)
{
     //Code
     SiteCollections si = ShareCollection[SiteGuid];
     SiteCollectionIterator(SiteCollection si)
}

void SiteCollectionIterator(SiteCollection si)
{
     //Code
     WebCollectionIterator w = SiteCollection [WebGuid];
     WebCollectionIterator(w)
}

void WebCollectionIterator(WebCollection w)
...
```

And so on until it has gone through each of the collections. I have therefore made 6 functions where the basics of the code is the same. Is there a way I can change this so the code is only written out once and can just call itself at the end and pass in the next collection? 
I tried to make and enumerator then at a counter in the function, but I couldn't get the enumerator to act as a classname. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think i poorly worded the title, but I have made an edit to the code, but each function actually returns void. Currently they just call the next function.

Comment: Make a base class for all the collections.  Then you iterator can use the base class as the iterator.  You iterator can then move from the end of one collection to then next collection.